# org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [templateId]

Tags: java, hibernate

Please find the code which I have used. Below HQL query fails saying that:

> could not locate named parameter [templateId]

But templateId exist in my model class.

Please help to resolve the issue or possible reason to get this type of error:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();         
                Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
                String hql ="from FieldTemplate where templateId= :id";
                Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
                query.setParameter("templateId", id);
                List file=query.list();
                tx.commit();
                return (FieldTemplate) file.get(0);
```

Model file

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EDW_FIELDS")
public class FieldTemplate {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int Id;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="TEMPLATE_ID")
    private int templateId;

    public int getTemplateId() {
        return templateId;
    }

    public void setTemplateId(int templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
    }

    @Column(name="FIELD_NAME")
    private String fieldName;

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    @Column(name="DISPLAY_ORDER")
    private int displayOrder;

    public int getDisplayOrder() {
        return displayOrder;
    }

    public void setDisplayOrder(int displayOrder) {
        this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    }
}
```

Please help to resolve my problem

Answer (score 25):

If it helps somebody, also remove any ; if your :param is at the very end of the query.

So for example, your query must be:

```
Select * from blah where param = :param
```

and NOT

```
Select * from blah where param = :param;
```

(note the ; at the end)

Comment: Is there a particular reason for this? Ran into this today but would like to understand why it happens...

Comment: No idea. It's just the way its designed. IT COULD BE the ; is used only as a delimiter in IDEs (like SQLYog or SQL Developer). It isn't really part of an error-free query, and that's why it throws an error when added inside a JPA statement.

Answer (score 12):

Your parameter name is `id` not `templateId`. You have to Change to:

```
String hql ="from FieldTemplate where templateId= :id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

The Name after `:` is the parameter name and must match the first parameter of `setParameter()`

Answer (score 0):

```
String hql ="from FieldTemplate where templateId= :id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql); 
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

in query.set parameter both should match

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Answers are typically better received if you give more context / explanation to the code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue as well and hard time finding that my **query was malformed**, and had **single quote not ended**...

```
SELECT * FROM Nuts WHERE FOO LIKE ':firstParamName AND BAR=:secondParamName
```

The error I had was mentioning that it was expecting for the second only in the list one of [firstParamName]

BTW for Java code, I like to use

```
final String PARAM_SOME_NAME = ":fooValueParam"
QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Nuts WHERE FOO LIKE " + PARAM_SOME_NAME
Query nativeQry = em.createNativeQuery(QUERY)
nativeQry.setParameter(PARAM_SOME_NAME.substring(1), aValue)
```

to avoid typos...